# Manage User Privileges in cPanel

Tags: mysql, database, cpanel

Is cPanel's Manage User Privileges (database and username connection privileges) trustable?

i have a username connected to a database which can **only SELECT** , and another username connected to the same database which can **INSERT and SELECT**

i have used the SELECT-only one in a not-so-secure script
can i trust this Privileges so no one can INSERT anything with this username?

Is this a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cpanel is just a GUI (& the nicest imho) to set your database privileges settings. Since most webserver won't allow you to connect directly to the database server through a terminal or to manage privileges through phpmyadmin, it's the easiest way to do it.

Then it's up to you only to secure your code against sql injection which is good practice

see http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: so if i set a username just ability to SELECT it can't ever INSERT or DROP? , i just dont want my table rows to be dropped in anyway by "php script"

Comment: in theory but the good practice is anyway to secure your queries against injection (see the link)